# Using regex to capture all instances of a particular character within another match

Tags: regex, notepad++

I have some text that looks like the following:

```
"tbl_One"."Column Name A" AS "Column Name A",
"tbl_Two"."Column Name B" AS "Column Name B",
"tbl_Three"."Column Name C" AS "Column Name C",
```

I want to select all of the spaces on each line that come after the *AS*, except for the one immediately following the *AS*.

I've been experimenting on this site: https://regex101.com/

I've come up with this so far, which captures the part of each line that I actually want to search for space characters:

```
/(?<=AS ).*(?=$)/gm
```

So, for example, on the first line, this captures:

```
"Column Name A",
```

I now want to tell it "OK, discard all of the characters you've captured except for the spaces".

How can I achieve this? This is going to be used in Notepad++ to remove all of the captured spaces.

Comment: Are all of these spaces expected to appear in between the double quoted substring that occurs right after `AS`  word?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew It's whichever engine Notepad++ uses, which apparently is "Boost". I'm going to remove the spaces using Notepad++'s find and replace.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Yes, all of the spaces will be between the double-quoted substring after the AS word.

Comment: And final check: can there be quotation marks inside the double quoted substring? Like `"Column ""here"""`? Sorry, just need to double check before posting a solution.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew No, not in the files that I have.

Answer (score 0):

You may use

*Find What*: `(?:\G(?!^)|\bAS\s+")[^\s"]*\K\h+`
*Replace With*: `<empty string>`

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/LEGLeg/1)

**Details**

- `(?:\G(?!^)|\bAS\s+")` - either the end of the previous successful match (`\G(?!^)`) or (`|`) the word `AS` as a whole word (`\b` is a word boundary) followed with 1+ whitespaces (can be replaced with `\h+` if there can be no line breaks here)
- `[^\s"]*` - any 0+ chars other than whitespace and `"`
- `\K` - match reset operator that zeros the text matched so far
- `\h+` - 1+ horizontal whitespace chars.

Notepad++ settings screenshot:

[image]

Comment: OK, that is amazing. Thank you so much! I will have to study it to see if I can learn how it works.